# ArcObjects: How to get the midpoint of a set of polylines?

Tags: arcobjects

How can I find the midpoint (along the curve) of a set of polylines using ArcObjects?

Answer (score 3):

There are probably several ways to do this but here is one that should work:

1. Union the input polylines into a single geometry using [`ITopologicalOperator.Union`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000003w2000000)
2. Cast the resulting geometry to [`ICurve`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ICurve_Interface/002m00000108000000/) and call [`ICurve.QueryPoint`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m00000115000000) with `DistanceAlongCurve` = 0.5 and `asRatio` = true. **Note:** this method will likely throw an error if the geometries are disjointed.
3. Do what you need with the output [`IPoint`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000026v000000)